# related records of parent table in many to many relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Table 1: `categories: id,name,parent_id`

```
id   name        parent_id
1    Vehicle     null
2    Car         1
3    Sedan       2

Vehicle > Car > Sedan
```

Table 2: `features: id, name`

```
id   name 
1    type
2    cylinder
3    color
4    weight
```

Table 3: `category_feature: category_id, feature_id`

```
category_id  feature_id
1            1
1            2
2            3
3            4
```

I could get all features by parent (category).

for example with this:

Category model:

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class);
}
```

And:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$features = $category->features()->get();
```

How can I get by a child category
all the features of the child and the features of the father's categories?

something like this:

```
$category = Category::find(3);
$features = $category->parent_features()->get();
```

I want it return these: type,cylinder,color,weight

Comment: How about ```
$category = Category::find(3);
$features = $category::with('hasParent')->features()->get(); 
```
Assuming you have relationship set up for in category to check if it has a parent.

Answer (score 0):

On **Categories** model:

```
public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class);
}
```

Then you can load it in one go:

```
$category = Category::with(['features', 'parent' => function($query){
     $query->with('features');
}])->find(3);
```

And then you can pull the parent's features:

```
$features = $category->parent->features;
```

Or the original car's features:

```
$originalFeatures = $category->features;
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked your code. `$category->parent->features` only return first parent features.  `$category->features` return null. So I missed features of current category  and root category.